# Scraping a Table from a Website using Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrape

I have tried several ways that works for other websites but not for this url.

https://www.wunderground.com/hourly/es/barcelona/IBARCE215/date/2022-07-25
Date (e.g. 2022-07-25) should be in the future

I tried

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/hourly/es/barcelona/IBARCE215/date/2022-07-25'
page = requests.get(url)
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')
```

But tr_elements is empty
It works with
url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/dashboard/pws/ISANSA11/table/2021-11-30/2021-11-30/daily'
url = 'http://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all'
But not with url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/hourly/es/barcelona/IBARCE215/date/2022-07-25'

I also tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/hourly/es/barcelona/IBARCE215/date/2022-07-20'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
table1 = soup.find('table', id='hourly-forecast-table')
```

But table is not found.
It works with:
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
table1 = soup.find('table', id='main_table_countries_today')

In Chrome I used “Ctrl + U” and “Ctrl + Shift + I” to see HTML
In url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/hourly/es/barcelona/IBARCE215/date/2022-07-25' I can see id='hourly-forecast-table' using “Ctrl + Shift + I” but not “Ctrl + U”.
I can not see neither in the code in soup variable.
In url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/' I see id='main_table_countries_today' using also “Ctrl + U”
I guess there is something different in this website.

Thank you very much,

Comment: Looking for related tutorial on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTiXxN3bD-Y&list=UUsFz0IGS9qFcwrh7a91juPg

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using this with [Selenium](https://pythonalgos.com/web-scraping-the-easy-way-python-selenium-beautiful-soup/) as well as Beautiful Soup? Get Selenium and Chromedriver and you can use it to replicate the keystrokes you use like "Ctrl+U" using Selenium's `send_key` function.